# static IP address, ssl certificate, and the root of all evil

Tags: apache, ssl, ip

I have a question, I fear the answer.

I have: 
a top level domain name (free from Tokelau, a territory of New Zealand, .tk, where else?), 
a free 2 year ssl certificate from startSSL.com, 
a free hosting package.

Now I jumped through every hoop startSSL wanted (admittedly wasn't too difficult), to get me my 2 year ssl certificate, and now I fear I have encountered a final barrier to success that might still stall my plans. I dreamt of a corner certificate stating "Secured by startSSL". I got the code snippet and everythings, and have pasted it into my website.

Problem. my host is not so keen on a free package to allow me to ssl.
As far as I know you need access to some config files to allow this to happen?
or can you just like with .htaccess and .htpassword files do the setting on your webhost?

Also you need a static IP. Are there any workarounds?

Or am I dreaming? Anyone with advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL Requires some files and configuration changes, pointing to the files.

Also, the static IP is required because with an encrypted request, there's no way to know to what host the request is intended without decryption. The use of a static IP address gives that request a destination.

To clarify: when using virtual hosts, multiple hosts will share the same IP address, so when a request comes in, the first two lines are:

```
GET /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

Apache (or any web server), looks at the 'Host' field to determine how to route the request. If the request is encrypted, there's no way to determine how to route the request, and you need to know what certificate to use in order to decrypt it.

Comment: Regardless of whether clients use SSL, the destination - that is, the server's IP - is known before any HTTP requests leave the client.

Comment: I guess I didn't clarify the assumption I made, which is that the site is hosted as a virtual host, so as it comes in, it wouldn't know to which virtual host the request belongs until it decrypts the request. The term `static IP` in that context is meaningless unless they're using virtual hosts.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification.  For reference, modern browsers and servers do/can actually get around the problem you describe using [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), but it's certainly something that requires the cooperation of the webspace provider.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to mention SNI, but it requires client browser compatibility (which is fairly good, actually), and configuration on the server. And I couldn't remember that much about it, quite frankly.

Answer (score 3):

Forget it. If your host doesn't have SSL configured, you have no chance to add it without their help

Comment: Ah. But are there any hosters (free web hosters) who might see this as an exciting add-on that might make their customers choose them! cos for free is meant to improve to for paid and all the rest.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your proposed set-up.

1. Free hosts generally don't provide a control panel interface to allow installation of SSL Certificates (at least I've never seen it) as this requires either their help on the back-end or VPS / Dedicated Server access from the front-end.
2. Static IP address is a must for SSL certificate installation.

Comment: Why would a static IP be required, or have anything to do with SSL setup?

Comment: My assumption is that the free hosting is being hosted as a 'virtual host'; this means that inbound requests to the server would need a static IP in order know which 'virtual host' to direct the request to until it decrypts the request.

Comment: A curiosity: so there are no hosts or servers who can dynamically shift the IP address to whom so ever the certificate belongs, a sort of choose that one option?

Comment: @John: Suppose you are running the free hosting service on IP 1.2.3.4. Suppose you have 10 virtual hosts running SSL and 50 running unsecured services on this one IP. Now you receive a TCP SYN packet destined for 1.2.3.4:443. Which virtual host do you deliver it to?

Comment: Per my comments above, [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) is how modern servers solve this problem.  [Apache](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) uses SNI for all name-based virtual hosts; other servers may require more setup.

Answer (score 0):

From webserver perspective, SSL cert is about a port and an IP address, even when being used with Name-based virtual hosts.

SSL is about the IP the matching the cert and domain in the URL/request(to verify the cert).

You would have to give a second SSL cert different port or different IP address on the webserver.

Alternatively, you can also get multi-domain and wildcard certs that allow different hostnames or domains to match the cert with different client request URLs, but the cert is still the only thing on that port/IP of the webserver.

### Just my $.02